# Can one of the Shift, Ctrl, Alt or Win keys be used in other purpose like, to type text?

Tags: java, windows, operating-system, keyboard-events

I want to modify the use of the one of the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd> keys. For example, if I just hit (not hold it and press another key) the <kbd>right shift</kbd> key, it should do something like displaying a special character in a text box. Could some one let me know if this is possible using any programming language like Java?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that.

Check this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) on how to write a **Key Listener** in **Java + Swing**.

Another interesting [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) about **Key Bindings** in **Java + Swing** that could also be useful. In order to define special reactions to particular keys use this tutorial.

Hope it helps.

Comment: glad to help! :D @MohammadRezaSelim you should mark my answer(or any other) as "THE" answer to your question if you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably a bit confusing for the user because it is not the usual expected behavior, but you can just wait for a specific key event. If want to map like `CTRL + N` to create a new file you are doing the same except you are looking for a combination of keys. The concrete implementation depends on what you specific java application you want to develop. But I think the implementation would be a case for SO.